# Is there another meaning of cow baby?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is baby cow used in another context as for calf? I've just received the message

> Our cow baby died today

Is it possible that he talks about something else than a calf?

This was mentioned in a small talk conversation like:

```
A: "Hey, how are you?"
B: "Hey, not so good. Our cow baby died today."
```

He's from India. I don't know if it's common to keep cows there. However, he's not a "real" farmer at all.

Comment: That might explain why the speaker said "cow baby" and not "baby cow", who knows. Usually with larger animals we add *baby* in front, such as *baby bear*, *baby elephant*, *baby dolphin*, but "cow baby" is a bit unusual.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Mentioned my edit? Does "cow baby" differ from "baby cow" somehow?

Comment: No, I wouldn't say so. It's funny how "cow baby" sounds quite natural, "elephant baby" works too, but not "bear baby" or "lion baby".... interesting.

Comment: The only one who knows what it *exactly* means and if he talks about something else than a calf is your friend in India.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cow baby is just what is sound like - a calf. He might be a milk vendor as it is common in India for people in semi - rural areas to open a stable for cows and sell their milk. Also, some people in urban areas will keep a cow as people just want to keep continuing the tradition that was followed by their ancestors